# window.close not working: some websites cannot be closed from the parent window

Tags: javascript

Some websites can be closed from the parent window, such as Google.

```
const winHandle = window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
setTimeout(() => {
  winHandle.close();  // work
}, 2000);
```

But some websites cannot be closed from the parent window, such as Facebook.

```
const winHandle = window.open('https://www.facebook.com', '_blank');
setTimeout(() => {
  winHandle.close();  // not working
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Did you mean `setTimeout`?